# adding active for menu 2 levels, hiliting 2 levels menu jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a 2-level menu and when i click on the first level its highlighting in yellow and working fine.

However, when i choose a category from the second level,  i would like for the main category in the first level to also be highlighted so that the user know which one of the main categories he's browsing.

this is my site:
http://www.marseille-fitness.com/bodypump.php

```
<ul class="mainNav">
    <li><a href="rpm.php">Cours collectifs</a>
        <ul class="dropDown">
            <li><a href="rpm.php">RPM</a></li>
            <li><a href="bodypump.php">Bodypump</a></li>
            <li><a href="bodyattack.php">Bodyattack</a></li>
            <li><a href="bodycombat.php">Bodycombat</a></li>
            <li><a href="bodyJam.php">Bodyjam</a></li>
            <li><a href="bodybalance.php">Bodybalance</a></li>
            <li><a href="cxworx.php">Cxworx</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>

<script>



        $("ul.mainNav li").hover(function(){
        $(this).find("ul.dropDown").css({"display" : "block"}).fadeTo('500', '1.0');
    }, function() {
        $(this).find("ul.dropDown").fadeTo('500', '0.0').css({"display" : "none"});
    });
        //class active in menu start
    $(function(){

        var url = window.location.pathname;
        var urlRegExp = new RegExp(url.replace(/\/$/,'')); // create regexp to match current url pathname and remove trailing slash if present as it could collide with the link in navigation in case trailing slash wasn't present there

        // now grab every link from the navigation
        $('.mainNav li a').each(function(){
            // and test its href against the url pathname regexp
            if(urlRegExp.test(this.href)){
                $(this).addClass('active');

            }
        });

    });

</script>
```

CSS

```
    @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:600,800);

ul.mainNav {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style-type:none;
    background-color: #f0eff0;
    height: 28px;
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    color: #606060;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 100px;

}
.menu-wrapper{
    background-color: #f0eff0;
    height: 3.4em;
}


.mainNav li {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style-type:none;
    height: 28px;
    line-height:28px;
    float: left;
    color: #606060;
    font-size: 14px;
}
.mainNav li a {
    padding: 0 20px;
    line-height: 3.8em;
    display:block;
    color: #606060;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 800;
}

.mainNav li:hover > a {
    background: #ffffff;
}

.mainNav li a:hover{
    background: #ffffff;
}

.mainNav li ul.dropDown {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    background: #fff;
    opacity: 0.0;
}
.mainNav li ul.dropDown li {
    float: left;
    height: 28px;
    line-height: 28px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #606060;
    /*font-weight: normal;*/

}
.mainNav li ul.dropDown li a {
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 3em;
    height: 28px;
    display:block;
    padding: 0 20px;
    color: #606060;
}
.mainNav li ul.dropDown li a:hover {
    background: #CFCFCF;
}

.img-logo-coach-menu {
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 5em;
}

.active {
    background: yellow;
}
```

Comment: seems the problem is only with the second menu

Comment: When i click on one of the item from the 2nd menu, i want the category in the first menu that this element belongs to also be highlighted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the loop to

```
var url = window.location.pathname;
var urlRegExp = new RegExp(url.replace(/\/$/,''));
$('.mainNav li a').each(function(){
        // and test its href against the url pathname regexp
        if(urlRegExp.test(this.href)){
            $(this).addClass('active');
            $(this).closest('.mainNav>li').children('a').addClass("active");
        }
    });
```

The `closest` function finds the first (closest) ancestor matching the selector, then you can add the class to it's direct child.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
$(this).addClass('active');
```

to

```
$(this).add($(this).parents('.mainNav li > a')).addClass('active');
```